# Google Maps is not displayed when I have a div before my map_canvas div

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Maps API v3 in a html file.

The following code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps simple</title>
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            myOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" align="center" style="width:60%; height:60% ; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if I put one div before my map_canvas div, my google maps is not displayed.

Example:

```
  <body>
  <div id="layout">
    <div id="toto">Hi everybody !!!!</div>
    <div id="map_canvas" align="center" style="width:60%; height:60% ; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have the `height:60% ;` in your nested example. If your `id="layout"` div doesn't have a set height to fill the body, the canvas will have a height of 60% of nothing. The div with the `id="toto"` will make the div height around 14px, so 60% of 14px is about 9px.

Try adding this css:

```
#layout {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: layout is in my css:

 div#layout {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 1;
 }

The issue is Google Maps not rendering my map_canvas, the div is in "gray", if i don't put some div before my map_canvas div, the google maps is displayed.

Have you some ideas?

thx